# Bug in zc.recipe.cmmi?

Tags: plone, buildout

If I provide a variable with an embedded space in the environment as follows:

```
environment =
    CPPFLAGS="-D_GNU_SOURCE -I${openssl:location}/include"
```

I get this error:

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/zc.buildout/+bug/393333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shortcoming in zc.recipe.cmmi; it cannot handle environment variables without spaces. There is a patch available in the [bugtracker for the recipe](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zc.buildout/+bug/393333).

I am not currently aware of a workaround for this other than applying the patch. You can apply the patch on existing eggs using the `collective.recipe.patch` recipe, which should work in this case too (untried):

```
[buildout]
parts =
    patch-z.r.cmmi
    yourcmmipart

[patch-z.r.cmmi]
recipe = collective.recipe.patch
egg = zc.recipe.cmmi <= 1.3.4
patch = patches/environ_section_trunk_r101308.patch
```

This assumes you have a `patches` suddirectory with the patch from the bug downloaded. The part needs to be listed before your cmmi part to be executed before that part (or you can fabricate a dependency).

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use plone.recipe.command instead. And did the configure, make, make install by hand. Worked well! Don't think i will use zc.recipe.cmmi again.

Comment: zc.recipe.cmmi does some great shared build managing that would be hard to reproduce with plone.recipe.command..

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to just abuse the recipe's 'configure-command' like so:

```
[buildthis]
recipe = zc.recipe.cmmi
...
configure-command =
  export CPPFLAGS="-D_GNU_SOURCE -I${openssl:location}/include";
  ./configure
```